# Is this 'pattern' ok or is there a better method?

Tags: c#, oop, derived-class, derived-types

I have several classes in my app (just a fragment):

```
public abstract class Element {...}

public abstract class Program : Element
{
    ...

    public void SpecificProgramCall();
}
```

When I know a variable patch is of subtype Program I use:

```
((Program) element).SpecificProgramCall();
```

or better:

```
var patch = patch as Program;
Debug.Assert(patch != null);
patch.SpecificProgramCall();
```

When I don't know if it is a program:

```
var patch = patch as (Program);
if (patch != null)
{
    patch.SpecificProgramCall();
}
```

However, my code is (will be) full of these constructs. Is there a better way to implement this?

Example:

```
var usedProgramBank = ((SetListSlot) setListSlot).UsedPatch.Parent as ProgramBank;
var key = new Tuple<ProgramBank, Program>(usedProgramBank, ((SetListSlot) setListSlot).UsedPatch as Program);
if (_dict.ContainsKey(key) && !_dict[key].Contains(setListSlot))
{
    _dict[key].Add(setListSlot);
}
```

Comment: That depends on where and why you would need such a construct. An interface and a call to `.OfType<IProgram>()` will help a lot, but whether it's applicable depends on the rest of your (calling) code.

Comment: I need it because a lot of the code is depending on the sub type (since functions are specific for a sub type).

Comment: That part is clear from your question, I was implicitly asking for you to show how you call this code. There is no quick fix at this level, a better approach can be defined depending on how you use this code.

Comment: Example added, I think I should think about making more code more generic so there is no NEED to cast more than needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more specific information about these types (including their semantics, your access to their code, etc), I'd say that this pattern is generally a candidate for dynamic dispatch. For example:

```
public abstract class Element
{
    public virtual void MaybeSpecificCall()
    {
        // nothing in most cases
    }
}

public abstract class Program : Element
{
    public override void MaybeSpecificCall()
    {
        base.MaybeSpecificCall();

        // but in this specific case, do something
        SpecificProgramCall(); 
    }

    public void SpecificProgramCall() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Then you can just do `patch.MaybeSpecificCall()` at the call spots and let the dynamic dispatch mechanism decide between doing something and doing nothing.

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to mess with the base class and you're only interested in not seeing the 'ugly' type checks, then a helper method could do the trick:

```
static void IfProgram(this Element element, Action<Program> action)
{
    var program = element as Program;
    if(program != null) action.Invoke(program);
}
```

And, again, you call it using `patch.IfProgram(x => x.SpecificProgramCall())`. I personally like lambdas, but whether they're ugly for this job is up to you.

Comment: Actually, my function is of the last type, really specific, so putting it in the base class is generically not a good idea.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers You either have to declare it in a statically known common type (either the base class or an interface that your classes will declare) and live with the fact that some of the classes will contain an empty implementation (which is not unheard of and not necessarily bad at all, but its validity depends on the semantics of those classes) or simply check at runtime (as you are already doing). The latter can maybe be extracted as a helper method (see edit), but it's only an aesthetic change: you eventually *have* to perform a check - but you can hide it under the rug a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of behavior you want from your code.  If you declare a SpecificProgramCall() method in class Element as virtual, then you can override it in derived classes.  In the base class you can either throw an error or handle it gracefully.  That could simplify code for calls to SpecificProgramCall.

For example, if SpecificProgramCall returns an object, then in the base class you could return null and in the derived class return an object.  Then all you have to do is check if the result of SpecificProgramCall is null.

There has to be accountability somewhere in your code if you're using polymorphism.  Where you want to put it is up to you and ultimately depends on the structure of the rest of the program.

Comment: Actually, my function is of the last type, really specific, so putting it in the base class is generically not a good idea. However, I like the null method, although I rather would then change it into two function calls, like: IsSpecificFunctionPossible? giving a bool and being able to call the other one (which might be specific).

Comment: if that's the case then I would suggest using "is", as in: if (patch is Program) { patch.SpecificProgramCall(); } else { /*do something else*/ }

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the 'is' method. That's indeed probably most elegant.